# Parent Child relation in sales force between a custom object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using `Salesforece` API via .Net (C#) I try to implement  a Parent - child Relation between a custom object.

Whichever is going to be detail object create a master detail field which would point to the other object. this would achieve the relationship. I want to Create a Parent as well as Child custom object at a same time ? is there any way to create a parent - child  relationship between a custom object via foreign keys?

When given Object reference to its parent Object `Salesforce` give error status:

> More than 1 field provided in an external foreign key reference in entity: ChidObj__c